# C18 sprintf() gives syntax error

Tags: c, c89, c17

I seem to have a syntax error on the line

```
FSFILE *file;
```

in the following code after adding the sprintf() line. The code worked up until i added the char text, textresult and sprintf(). I can't seem to find out what's wrong with it. I'm using the C18 compiler. the code is for writing data to an SD card using SPI. the char txt[] is a value from a measurement with a temperature sensor, for example: 23,5. But I want to add more text to this. The goal is to store every 5 minutes a measurement on the SD card, along with a timestamp or something. i'm using a PIC18f27j53.

```
void writeFile()
{
    unsigned char txt[]={ftc(result,0),ftc(result,1),0x2C,ftc(result,3)};
    unsigned char text[]= "hello";  
    unsigned char textresult[];   
    sprintf(textresult, "%c%c", txt, text); 
    //unsigned char size = sizeof(result)-1;
    FSFILE *file;
    file = FSfopenpgm("DATA.TXT", "w");
    if(file == NULL)while(1);
    if(FSfwrite((void *) txt, 1, 4, file)!=4)while(1);
    if(FSfclose(file)!=0)while(1);
}
```

Comment: Is `sprintf()` really relevant? Doesn't it just mean that your compiler doesn't support declareing variables in the middle of function after writing some non-declaretion statements?

Comment: `unsigned char textresult[];   
    sprintf(textresult, "%c%c", txt, text); ` undefined behaviour!!! because `textresult` isn't allocated!!

Comment: `textresult` is an empty array, how can you write soomething in an empty array? Also `txt` is a pointer, `%c` expects a `char`

Comment: Isn't PIC18 an 8-bitter? Why are you using sprintf on a 8 bit MCU? It is not a PC - you just blew up the whole memory map. If you need to use such a resource-heavy function just to copy 2 strings, which you even fail to do correctly, there's no hope for this project. Hand it over to an embedded systems programmer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `sprintf(...)` after where you declare your variables.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what `ftc` does but your `txt` might not be `'\0'`-terminated, if
you want to use it as a string, it has to be `'\0'`-terminated.

Also your `textresult` is an empty array, what do you expect will happen if you
try to write stuff where there is not space available?

```
unsigned char textresult[20];
```

would be correct.

Also note that `%c` in `printf` expects a single `char` value, you are passing a
pointer to a whole sequence of `char`s, that's undefined behavior. You have to
either use `%s` (and for this `txt` must be `'\0'`-terminated) or you pass
`txt[0]`, a single `char`:

```
sprintf(textresult, "%c%c", txt[0], text); 

// or

unsigned char txt[]={ftc(result,0),ftc(result,1),0x2C,ftc(result,3), 0};
...
sprintf(textresult, "%s%c", txt, text);
```

And if you compiler want all variables to be declare at the beginning of the
function, move the

```
FSFILE *file;
```

before the `sprintf` call.